# how to obtain button content size dynamically in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a button that has dynamic width according to its content. When I put the word 'next' for example, it gets the size it should be, but when this button goes to the loading state and displays the spinner it adjusts to the size of the spinner. How can I solve this and leave it the size of the previous content?

```
<Container isDisabled={disabled} {...props}>
    {loading ? <Spinner /> : children}
</Container>
```

I’m using styled components to style. The reference of the width is the child, I want to leave the 2 in the same size

Ideal size

[image: Ideal button size]

Button in loading state that should be in the ideal size

[image: Button in loading state that should be in the ideal size]

Comment: Use `useRef` with `offsetWidth` to preserve the width.

Comment: I researched about the two but I couldn't see how it would help to obtain the width of the children, could you indicate a tutorial?

Comment: Could you please create some working example on codesandbox?

Comment: You could solve it by css (see below). I have used line-height below but you could use padding or margin or whatever you need. I would argue that this is a much simpler solution than solving the issue in code.

.button .spinner {
  line-height: *same as your text*
}

Comment: but the width will be dynamic, I have no way, Kamelkent. I want to solve with Css, but I don't know how

Comment: I can create, Medi. But it is very simple, not seven width, I want the width of the children to predominate and not of the spinner even when loading. In addition to this excerpt that I put in the question, it has only the style